# How to send MQTT packets generated with mqtt-packet library?

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I am trying to build mqtt packets with custom payloads and I have found this node library https://github.com/mqttjs/mqtt-packet as it seems to give me freedom to create custom payloads for testing. However I don't see how, after creating the packets, I could send them to a MQTT broker. Do I need then an MQTT client that accepts the packets I create with the mqtt-packet?
If you have any other suggestions to create and send custom mqtt packets it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use this to generate custom payloads?

Comment: I was searching for a library that would allow me to inject random payloads into MQTT packets and this the library that I found that seems to provide that functionality. But I am very new to MQTT and I am in the learning process, so for sure I am missing many things.

Answer (score 1):

MQTT message payloads are just byte arrays, you can send anything you want in them.

The package you have found is for use inside a MQTT client implementation to build the actual low level packets needed to implement the MQTT protocol.

You should be just using a normal MQTT client e.g. the [MQTT.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) library.

If you want to send messages with binary payloads you can just pass a Buffer to the `publish` method. From the [MQTT.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#mqttclientpublishtopic-message-options-callback):

> **mqtt.Client#publish(topic, message, [options], [callback])**
>
> Publish a message to a topic
>
> *topic* is the topic to publish to, String
>
> *message* is the message to publish, Buffer or String
>
> *options* is the options to publish with, including:
>
> - qos QoS level, Number, default 0
> - retain retain flag, Boolean, default false
> - dup mark as duplicate flag, Boolean, default false
>
>   callback - function (err), fired when the QoS handling completes,
>     or at the next tick if QoS 0. An error occurs if client is
>     disconnecting.

Comment: additionally to what is above, if you want to receive the payloads that you sent, with the same MQTT client, all you need to do is just subscribe to the same topic on which you do the publish

Comment: I thought about mqtt-package as I had read about an issue when the client sends a payload that is not of the length declared in the header and I wanted to try see what happens. With the MQTT.js I imagine the headers are created based on the payload. I'll have a look to see what I can get to with the suggestions you gave. Thank you.

Comment: OK, it's really not clear from your question that you are deliberately trying to send broken/malformed packets (not payloads). If you are looking to do this sort of testing I suggest you look at the source for MQTT.js and how it uses mqtt-packet and modify that.